# Tensorflow-gpu v1.14 is ignoring my GPU (Nvidia GTX 860M) with compute capability 3.0/5.0(**).

Tags: python, tensorflow

This may be a repeated question but I could not find a solution to it yet. Currently, I am running TF-gpu 1.6.0 with CUDA 9.0 and cuDNN 7.0.5 which is working fine and resulting in TRUE if I type

`tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)`.

But I need to install TF-gpu v1.14 to work on something that requires TF-gpu v1.14. But when I install TF-gpu v1.14 with compatible CUDA and cuDNN and type the above command again, it results in FALSE and these commands

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

only shows my CPU not the GPU. As I wrote in the title that Tensorflow-gpu v1.14 is ignoring my GPU (Nvidia GTX 860M) with compute capability 3.0/5.0 (**) and it requires minimum compute capability of  3.5.

Following is the link that I used to find the compute capability of my GPU.

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

I am running

```
Windows 10

Pycharm-2019.2
```

Can you please guide me on how can I solve this problem? I would be highly thankful.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the correct CUDA and cuDNN versions and that the new tensorflow version is not using the old CUDA versions?. Try removing the old CUDA and cuDNN versions and check again.The tensorflow website says that CUDA required for v1.14 is CUDA 10 and cuDNN 7.4.

Comment: Yes. I uninstalled CUDA and cuDNN correctly as stated in 2.3.1 in https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#uninstall-cuda-software. Then I installed TF-gpu v1.14 with CUDA 10 and cuDNN 7.4.

Comment: use anaconda you can easily able to install it, you just need to have nvidia drivers installed, no need to install cuda and cudnn .  anaconda will handle everythng

Comment: It is still not working!